# How can I prevent codeigniter clearing form input fields on unsuccessful validation?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have an html form in a view that has validation rules set in it's controller, the problem I'm having is that when someone sends data that isn't valid I want to maintain the data in those fields at the client side, if I reload the view, the fields are cleared, how can I maintain the fields in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're coding your input fields the long way:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="" />
```

You can use the [Form Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)'s `set_value()` function to return values to the input.

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity');?>" />
```

For `<select>` fields, checkboxes and radio buttons, there is `set_select()`, `set_checkbox()` and `set_radio()`.

Comment: FYI missing closing php tag

Answer (score 1):

Please read this **[CI Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)**.

Using `set_value()` you can prevent codeigniter clearing form input fields on unsuccessful validation.

Like :

```
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to avoid this.

First,you can use ajax submit instead of get or post submit.If you ajax submit successfully,then you use javascript submit your form!

Another way to avoid this store the submit data to session.If valid failed,reput the session stored data to your reloded view!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to retain the values after you reload the view you'll need to use [session user_data](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) or store the values somewhere in your db.  I don't think that is what you mean, I think you are referring to the data that is showing after the submit (aka the `$_POST` data).

In your view you could use a ternary operator like this:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?=isset($_POST['first_name'] ? $_POST['first_name'] : NULL ?>"/>
```

There are other ways to manage this as well from your controller.  For example you could define a variable `$first_name` from your controller like this:

```
if(isset($_POST[]){
     //form_validation
     $vars['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
}else{
     $vars['first_name'] = NULL;
}
$this->load->view('your_view',$vars);
```

Then in your view you would simply set the value of the input as `$first_name`